# problem with vue-html2pdf in Persian language

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Do you have any idea to solve problem with Persian language in vue-html2pdf?
or are there any other module for convert VUE to PDF without problem in RTL language??

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't support persian text in HTML? Its unclear what problem you are having?

Comment: yes, it shows Persian in reverse because Persian is rtl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use "html2pdf.js" module in vue for make pdf in persian language and i have your problem in it but then i found out that its because of some css in the css framework in my project and i realize this css is "word-wrap" and i change it to "word-wrap: initial;" in the area that i want to make pdf from it and it work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

#### vuejs

you need to add **'p'** tag in 'pdf-content' slot that fill in in scrips and you have to add style 'text align right' and 'float right' which can solve it

```
<section slot='pdf-content' class='p-5 m-3'>
   <p id='PDFFulltext' style='text-align: right; float: right'></p>
</section>
```

```html
<b-button @click='generateReport()'>export</b-button>
<b-button @click='placeText()'>btn</b-button>
```

```
methods: {
        placeText() {
          var full_text = `<p>متن فارسی یا عربی</p>`;
          document.getElementById('PDFFulltext').innerHTML = full_text;
        },
        generateReport() {
          this.$refs.html2Pdf.generatePdf();
        },
}
```